# Linear-acceleration on iOS how do I get same data as from Android TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION?

Tags: ios

I have a question. Well I made an application for android device. Which returning me values of

```
 SensorManager sensorManager;
 Sensor sensor;
 sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
 sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);with 

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        xAxis   = event.values[0];
        zAxis   = event.values[2];
    }
```

Well I want to learn a bit about iOS and make this program for iOS system also. How can I do this lines for iOS ? I search a bit, but didn't really find something usefull.

Comment: Were you looking for detecting acceleration in each axis? If so, this is answer : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_accelerometer.htm

Comment: Thank you. Ye this is what I was looking for. Just one more question. Is this same as Linear acceleration in android ? or is this normal acceleration ?

Comment: This is linear acceleration. Sorry for misleading you. I just rechecked. It is depreciated. Please check my answer for doing it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Linear Acceleration = Force/mass = (ax, ay, az), it's a vector with components in 3 directions**

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

CMMotionManager *manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

if (manager.isAccelerometerAvailable) {
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01;
    [manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData * _Nullable accelerometerData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (accelerometerData != NULL) {
            CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;
            double x_acceleration = acceleration.x;
            double y_acceleration = acceleration.y;
            double z_acceleration = acceleration.z;
            double linear_acceleration = sqrt(pow(x_acceleration, 2) + pow(y_acceleration, 2) + pow(z_acceleration, 2));
            NSLog(@"linear_acceleration: %@", linear_acceleration);
        }
    }];
}
```

`UIAccelerometer` is depreciated and replaced with `CoreMotion` framework.